# Elasticsearch using NEST: How to configure analyzers to find partial words?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to make a search by partial word, ignoring casing and ignoring the accentuation of some letters. Is it possible? I think ngram with default tokenizer should do the trick but i don't understand how to do it with NEST.

Example: "musiic" should match records that have "music"

The version I am using of Elasticsearch is 1.9.

I am doing like this but it doesn't work...

```
var ix = new IndexSettings();
        ix.Add("analysis",
            @"{
               'index_analyzer' : {
                          'my_index_analyzer' : {
                                        'type' : 'custom',
                                        'tokenizer' : 'standard',
                                        'filter' : ['lowercase', 'mynGram']
                          }
               },
               'search_analyzer' : {
                          'my_search_analyzer' : {
                                        'type' : 'custom',
                                        'tokenizer' : 'standard',
                                        'filter' : ['standard', 'lowercase', 'mynGram']
                          }
               },
               'filter' : {
                        'mynGram' : {
                                   'type' : 'nGram',
                                   'min_gram' : 2,
                                   'max_gram' : 50
                        }
               }
    }");
        client.CreateIndex("sample", ix);
```

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

I think what you're looking for is a [fuzzy query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/fuzzy-query.html), which uses the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to match similar words.

**Long Answer on nGrams**

The nGram filter splits the text into many smaller tokens based on the defined min/max range.

For example, from your 'music' query the filter will generate:
`'mu', 'us', 'si', 'ic', 'mus', 'usi', 'sic', 'musi', 'usic', and 'music'`

As you can see `musiic` does not match any of these nGram tokens.

**Why nGrams**

One benefit of nGrams is that it makes wildcard queries *significantly* faster because all potential substrings are pre-generated and indexed at insert time (I have seen queries speed up from multi-seconds to 15 milliseconds using nGrams).

Without the nGrams, each string must be searched at query time for a match [O(n^2)] instead of directly looked up in the index [O(1)].  As pseudocode:

```
hits = []
foreach string in index:
    if string.substring(query):
        hits.add(string)
return hits
```

vs

```
return index[query]
```

Note that this comes at the expense of making inserts slower, requiring more storage, and heavier memory usage.