# Creating an index Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, nest, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-analyzers

How would I recreate the following index using Elasticsearch Nest API?

Here is the json for the index including the mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "trigrams_filter": {
                    "type":     "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 3
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "trigrams": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter":   [
                        "lowercase",
                        "trigrams_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "data": {
        "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "trigrams" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```cs
var newIndex = client.CreateIndexAsync(indexName, index => index
            .NumberOfReplicas(replicas)
            .NumberOfShards(shards)
            .Settings(settings => settings
                .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
                .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
                .Add("mapping.allow_type_wrapper", true))
             .AddMapping<Object>(mapping => mapping
                .IndexAnalyzer("trigram")
                .Type("string"))
 );
```

The documentation does not mention anything about this?

UPDATE:

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788178/elasticsearch-using-nest-how-to-configure-analyzers-to-find-partial-words?rq=1) post that uses 
`var index = new IndexSettings()`

and then adds Analysis with the string literal json.

`index.Add("analysis", @"{json});`

Where can one find more examples like this one and does this work?

Comment: If you don't want to deal with lambda code, the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026007/elasticsearch-nest-create-an-index-through-elasticclient-by-specifying-json/29068816#29068816 describes how to pass raw json to an ElasticClient to create an index. This might be easier or more flexible in some use cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Creating an index in older versions

There are two main ways that you can accomplish this as outlined in the [Nest Create Index Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/create-indices.html):

Here is the way where you directly declare the index settings as Fluent Dictionary entries. Just like you are doing in your example above. I tested this locally and it produces the index settings that match your JSON above.

```cs
        var response = client.CreateIndex(indexName, s => s
          .NumberOfReplicas(replicas)
          .NumberOfShards(shards)
          .Settings(settings => settings
             .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
             .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
             .Add("mapping.allow_type_wrapper", true)
             .Add("analysis.filter.trigrams_filter.type", "nGram")
             .Add("analysis.filter.trigrams_filter.min_gram", "3")
             .Add("analysis.filter.trigrams_filter.max_gram", "3")
             .Add("analysis.analyzer.trigrams.type", "custom")
             .Add("analysis.analyzer.trigrams.tokenizer", "standard")
             .Add("analysis.analyzer.trigrams.filter.0", "lowercase")
             .Add("analysis.analyzer.trigrams.filter.1", "trigrams_filter")
           )
           .AddMapping<Object>(mapping => mapping
              .Type("data")
              .AllField(af => af.Enabled())
              .Properties(prop => prop
                 .String(sprop => sprop
                   .Name("text")
                   .IndexAnalyzer("trigrams")
                  )
               )
           )
       );
```

Please note that NEST also includes the ability to create index settings using strongly typed classes as well. I will post an example of that later, if I have time to work through it.

### Creating index with NEST 7.x

Please also note that in NEST 7.x `CreateIndex` method is removed. Use `Indices.Create` isntead. Here's the example.

```cs
_client.Indices
    .Create(indexName, s => s
        .Settings(se => se
            .NumberOfReplicas(replicas)
            .NumberOfShards(shards)
            .Setting("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")));
```

Answer (score 10):

In case people have NEST 2.0, the .NumberOfReplicas(x).NumberOfShards(y) are in the Settings area now so specify within the lamba expression under Settings.

```
        EsClient.CreateIndex("indexname", c => c
        .Settings(s => s
             .NumberOfReplicas(replicasNr)
             .NumberOfShards(shardsNr)
        )
```

NEST 2.0 has a lot of changes and moved things around a bit so these answers are a great starting point for sure. You may need to adjust a little for the NEST 2.0 update.

Comment: Thanks man - couldn't find this in the docs.  Of course until this comment I didn't really know what I was looking for exactly.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Small example :

```
            EsClient.CreateIndex("indexname", c => c
                .NumberOfReplicas(replicasNr)
                .NumberOfShards(shardsNr)
            .Settings(s => s
                 .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
                 .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "15s")
            )

            #region Analysis
           .Analysis(descriptor => descriptor
                .Analyzers(bases => bases
                    .Add("folded_word", new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Filter = new List<string> { "icu_folding", "trim" },
                        Tokenizer = "standard"
                    }
                    )

             .TokenFilters(i => i
                         .Add("engram", new EdgeNGramTokenFilter
                         {
                             MinGram = 1,
                             MaxGram = 20
                         }
                         )
            )
            .CharFilters(cf => cf
                         .Add("drop_chars", new PatternReplaceCharFilter
                         {
                             Pattern = @"[^0-9]",
                             Replacement = ""
                         }

            )
            #endregion

            #region Mapping Categories
            .AddMapping<Categories>(m => m
                .Properties(props => props
                    .MultiField(mf => mf
                            .Name(n => n.Label_en)
                            .Fields(fs => fs
                                .String(s => s.Name(t => t.Label_en).Analyzer("folded_word"))
                                )
                        )
             )
            #endregion
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has migrated to NEST 2.4 and has the same question - you would need to define your custom filters and analyzers in the index settings like this:

```
        elasticClient.CreateIndex(_indexName, i => i
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                        .EdgeNGram("edge_ngrams", e => e
                            .MinGram(1)
                            .MaxGram(50)
                            .Side(EdgeNGramSide.Front)))
                        .Analyzers(analyzer => analyzer
                            .Custom("partial_text", ca => ca
                                .Filters(new string[] { "lowercase", "edge_ngrams" })
                                .Tokenizer("standard"))
                            .Custom("full_text", ca => ca
                                .Filters(new string[] { "standard", "lowercase" } )
                                .Tokenizer("standard"))))));
```

Answer (score 1):

For 7.X plus you can use the following code to create an index with Shards, Replicas and with Automapping:

```
 if (!_elasticClient.Indices.Exists(_elasticClientIndexName).Exists)
        {
            var response = _elasticClient.Indices
                            .Create(_elasticClientIndexName, s => s
                                .Settings(se => se
                                    .NumberOfReplicas(1)
                                    .NumberOfShards(shards)
                                    ).Map<YourDTO>(
                                                x => x.AutoMap().DateDetection(false)
                                            ));



            if (!response.IsValid)
            {
                // Elasticsearch index status is invalid, log an exception

            }
        }
```